# Insert '-' between every 6 characters

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to make the text of an input be formatted by dividing the 48 numbers into blocks of 6 numbers, for example:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

becomes

```
000000-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000
```

These numbers are returned with a $response after submitting a form with CURL.

For some reason when the result returns it is not in this format, I need to erase a number and rewrite it so that it is corrected and in the correct format.

This is the code I'm using:

JS

```
$(window).on("load",
    function () {
        $("#resID").on("change paste input", function (e) {
            var t = this.value.replace(/\D/g, "");
            48 == t.length ? (this.value = t.match(new RegExp(".{1," + t.length / 6 + "}", "g")).join("-")) : (this.value = t)
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="response">
   <?php if($response != ''){ ?>
    <input type="search" class="form-control" id="resID" style="text-align: center;" value="<?php echo $response; ?>" data-clipboard-target="#resID" href="#" readonly>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

In short, it is formatting correctly but I need to update the numbers by deleting the last one and typing it in again.

Does anyone know what to be wrong?

Comment: Don't use a ternary in place of an `if` statement, it makes the code harder to read.

Comment: Ternary should be used in place of the value, e.g. `this.value = <condition> ? expression1 : expression2;`

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't fix it up in PHP?

Comment: Can you show an example of the number you need to fix the format of?

Comment: Hi Barmar, I tried it with PHP also using sprintf but I couldn't do the division correctly could you show me an example of how to use it?

Comment: The number that returns to me comes whole in a single block of numbers, e.g. 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: Trivial to do in PHP as well - just needs a combination of `str_split` and `implode`, https://3v4l.org/icIBU

Comment: @CBroe Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in one line. We can use  [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to split the string into an array of segments of 6 characters and [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to concatenate these parts together.

```js
var value = '000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000';
console.log(value.match(/.{1,6}/g).join("-"))
```

In your case:

```js
$(window).on('load', () => {
  $("#resID").on("change paste input", function(e) {
    this.value = this.value.match(/.{1,6}/g).join("-");
  })
})




/* below for demonstration purposes only */
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('set value to 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000');
  $('#resID').val('000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000').trigger('change');
}, 1000);
```

```css
input {
  width: 415px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" class="form-control" id="resID" style="text-align: center;" value="" data-clipboard-target="#resID" href="#" readonly>
```

Comment: That's a really nice answer!

Comment: It looks like the asker's issue is that their code to format the string is inside `$("#resID").on("change paste input", function (e) {` though.

Comment: concise answer we need more of you on SO. @Spectric

Comment: @Joundill Thanks for the reminder. I've updated my answer :)

Comment: Hey friends, thank you so much for everyone's help, I managed to solve the problem with your help.

Comment: @RafaelOliveira Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the substring in a for loop you can use the index to create a ***divisible*** section, the `index, index + 6`, push this into an array to get the parts that can be joined using the dash.

```js
let string = "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";

function addDashes(string) {
  let strArr = []
  for (let i = 0, len = string.length; i < len; i += 6) {
    strArr.push(string.substring(i, i + 6));
  }
  return strArr.join('-')
}

console.log(addDashes(string))
```

Comment: Hello friend, thank you very much for your help.